# What applications provide org.freedesktop.secrets.service

Tags: password-management, xfce, gnome-keyring

While trying out *google-chrome dev and beta channels' latest version (25)*, I was getting a `segmentation fault` problem causing Chrome to crash, right after showing a message informing that it was unable to locate a `.service` file that provides `org.freedesktop.secrets.service`. This problem was solved by either adding the flag `--password-store=basic` to use un-encrypted  passwords or by installing and starting *gnome-keyring*.

Is there an alternative to *gnome-keyring* to use with *google-chrome* (and optionally ssh-agent) in **xfce 4.10**?

Comment: which extensions installed? please disable all and retry

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the problem is not chrome crashing (that, I managed to fix). The question is about alternatives to **gnome-keyring**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GNOME Keyring implements the [Freedesktop Secret Service standard](http://standards.freedesktop.org/secret-service/). The only alternative that I know of is KDE's [`ksecretsservice`](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Utils/ksecretsservice). I'm not sure how complete it is; this is [the code repository](https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/utils/ksecrets/repository). It seems to be packaged in [the experimental Kubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/experimental).

Comment: Ow, KDE is really disappointing. I wanted to add support for this new API to [`kwalletcli`](https://www.mirbsd.org/kwalletcli.htm) and would have preferred using KDE’s client component there, as opposed to `libsecret`… but nothing there, the mailing list archvies are really sad…

Comment: A KDE contributor recently wrote that `ksecretsservice is dead. But KeePassXC works very well (as mentioned in another answer).

Answer (score 10):

Now there is also [KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org) which provides a Freedesktop Secret Service implementation.

Comment: KeePassXC has proven to be a great solution for me. I'm very happy with the way it works in regard to providing the Freedesktop Secret Service implementation.

Answer (score 4):

secret-service implements [Secret Service API](http://standards.freedesktop.org/secret-service) (org.freedesktop.secrets.service)

Repository address: https://github.com/yousefvand/secret-service

Answer (score 1):

[bitw](https://github.com/mvdan/bitw) provides an implementation of `org.freedesktop.secrets` for Bitwarden.